# A better java class to update property files without changing its format?

Tags: java, properties

I tried using **PropertiesConfiguration**, it help me what i wanted, but found an issue, if my property's value contains comma followed by a whitespace, after using **PropertiesConfiguration** for property update whitespace vanishes, can anyone try this or suggest me if any other method to edit property file without impacting its format

if anyone wish to try, you can set below property in a file and then using above code update property file, update other property instead of below property, let me know what is the outcome

```
property=value1, value2
```

Comment: Try enclosing the values in double quotes, `property="value1, value2"`

Comment: properties is legacy. Use Preferences : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226110/loading-a-map-using-properties-class/32226264#32226264

Comment: Tried adding double quotes, didn't work.
Also I am trying to add/update file for other properties, i don't want to change existing property by adding double quotes, because I am unaware of such possible occurrences in any other files

Comment: sunrise76 can you provide me code snippet how it needs to be done for .properties file, found examples related to .xml file and not .properties file

Answer (score 0):

You can escape every thing in properties file with Java Unicode:

```
\u003d for =
\u0020 for whitespace
```

For example:

```
foo bar = barefoot
```

must be:

```
foo\u0020bar\u0020=\u0020barefoot
```

So will be:

```
key: "foo bar "
value: " barefoot"
```

For your example it should look like the following:

```
property=value1,\u0020 value2
```

this should result in:

```
key: "property"
value: "value1, value2"
```

**If you cant change the format of your properties there are two solutions left:**

first. you can Split your String at the coma (","), then create a new String with whitespace:

```
String value = "value1,value2";
String[] parts = value.split(",");
String correctValue = parts[0] + " " + parts[1]
```

second.(not recommendet!)you can extend `java.util.Properties` and `override` this method

```
public synchronized void load(InputStream inStream) throws IOException
```

Comment: this will require me to edit old properties where whitespace is followed after comma, and i am not aware how many of such occurrences are present as there are lot many property files, i want to have a solution if such value is already present in a property file and if i try to update any other key or add a new key in this file it should not affect the property whose value contains comma followed by whitespace.

Comment: well i provided the solution. To display a whitespace in propertie you have to escape it with unicode. Therefore you setted your properties wrong from the beginning. if there is a comma everytime "value1, value2", why dont you get the value "value1,value2" without whitespace and add a whitespace after the comma?that would be possible