# Best file format to store Name and Value

Tags: java, ini

I'm creating a program in which I need to store an item name, and a value. The program will randomly choose things from the list based on the total value being lower then a set limit, and then printing the names of those items. What would be the best file to store this in? I was looking at an .ini file, but that seems to be for settings and such. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to store it on disk, or just in memory?  "Best" is relative - do you mean fastest, most compressed, easiest to program?  How many items?  Answer will be different if you have 2 compared to 2 billion.

Comment: How big is your list?  Does it need to be easy to edit?   A Java Properties file is a good choice, as @Leo mentioned.  Also, you might consider using a CSV file if you want to edit it with a spreadsheet program like Excel or OpenOffice.

Comment: List will probably be around 100 items. It doesn't need to be easy to edit, especially not by the user. By best I mean the fastest as I might have to loop through it several times. Another plus would be having categories if possible.

Answer (score 4):

The typical key-value text file storage in Java is the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

See [an example here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/).

Comment: I don't see it there, is there I way i could sort them into categories like an .ini file? Or will I just have to create a few different property files?

Answer (score 0):

In that case, use XML and preferences.

Have a look at my post to set Preferences from XML : [Loading a map using Properties class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226110/loading-a-map-using-properties-class/32226264#32226264)

Have a look at [Example 1](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/)  and  [Example 2](http://crunchify.com/java-simple-way-to-write-xml-dom-file-in-java/) links to write XML from java.