# How to fetch properties from dynamically generated pojo class

Tags: java, json

I am using the jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin v0.4.7 to generate POJO classes from a JSON schema.In that I want to fetch properties of pojo class which is generated dynamically .the pojo class contained onather pojo class.Is there is solution to read fields from pojo class which contains onather? for instance in this case I have Employee pojo in that there is Address object I want to fetch field of both classes.

below is my schema

```
    {
     "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
     "type": "object",
     "title":"Employee",
     "name":"Employee",
     "properties": {
     "empId": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "salary": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {

        "city": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "pincode": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "landMark":{
        "type": "string"
        }
     }

    },
    "phoneNo": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {

        "mobile": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "landLine": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
     }

    }
  }
}
```

pojo classes

1.Employee

```
 @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
  @Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
 @JsonPropertyOrder({
"empId",
"lastName",
"title",
"salary",
"address",
"phoneNo"
})
 public class Employee {

@JsonProperty("empId")
private Integer empId;
@JsonProperty("lastName")
private String lastName;
@JsonProperty("title")
private String title;
@JsonProperty("salary")
private Integer salary;
@JsonProperty("address")
private Address address;
@JsonProperty("phoneNo")
private PhoneNo phoneNo;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The empId
 */
@JsonProperty("empId")
public Integer getEmpId() {
    return empId;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param empId
 *     The empId
 */
@JsonProperty("empId")
public void setEmpId(Integer empId) {
    this.empId = empId;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The lastName
 */
@JsonProperty("lastName")
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param lastName
 *     The lastName
 */
@JsonProperty("lastName")
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The title
 */
@JsonProperty("title")
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param title
 *     The title
 */
@JsonProperty("title")
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The salary
 */
@JsonProperty("salary")
public Integer getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param salary
 *     The salary
 */
@JsonProperty("salary")
public void setSalary(Integer salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The address
 */
@JsonProperty("address")
public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param address
 *     The address
 */
@JsonProperty("address")
public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The phoneNo
 */
@JsonProperty("phoneNo")
public PhoneNo getPhoneNo() {
    return phoneNo;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param phoneNo
 *     The phoneNo
  enter code here     */
@JsonProperty("phoneNo")
public void setPhoneNo(PhoneNo phoneNo) {
    this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder().append(empId).append(lastName).append(title).append(salary).append(address).append(phoneNo).append(additionalProperties).toHashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if ((other instanceof Employee) == false) {
        return false;
    }
    Employee rhs = ((Employee) other);
    return new EqualsBuilder().append(empId, rhs.empId).append(lastName, rhs.lastName).append(title, rhs.title).append(salary, rhs.salary).append(address, rhs.address).append(phoneNo, rhs.phoneNo).append(additionalProperties, enter code hererhs.additionalProperties).isEquals();
}
```

}

2 Address

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
     @Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
    @JsonPropertyOrder({
   "city",
  "pincode",
  "landMark"
  })
public class Address {

@JsonProperty("city")
private String city;
@JsonProperty("pincode")
private Integer pincode;
@JsonProperty("landMark")
private String landMark;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String,        Object>();

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The city
 */
@JsonProperty("city")
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param city
 *     The city
 */
@JsonProperty("city")
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The pincode
 */
@JsonProperty("pincode")
public Integer getPincode() {
    return pincode;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param pincode
 *     The pincode
 */
@JsonProperty("pincode")
public void setPincode(Integer pincode) {
    this.pincode = pincode;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The landMark
 */
@JsonProperty("landMark")
public String getLandMark() {
    return landMark;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param landMark
 *     The landMark
 */
@JsonProperty("landMark")
public void setLandMark(String landMark) {
    this.landMark = landMark;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder().append(city).append(pincode).append(landMark).append(additionalProperties).toHashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if ((other instanceof Address) == false) {
        return false;
    }
    Address rhs = ((Address) other);
    return new EqualsBuilder().append(city, rhs.city).append(pincode, rhs.pincode).append(landMark, rhs.landMark).append(additionalProperties, rhs.additionalProperties).isEquals();
}
```

}

3.phoneNo

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"mobile",
"landLine"
})
public class PhoneNo {

@JsonProperty("mobile")
private Integer mobile;
@JsonProperty("landLine")
private Integer landLine;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The mobile
 */
@JsonProperty("mobile")
public Integer getMobile() {
    return mobile;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param mobile
 *     The mobile
 */
@JsonProperty("mobile")
public void setMobile(Integer mobile) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The landLine
 */
@JsonProperty("landLine")
public Integer getLandLine() {
    return landLine;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param landLine
 *     The landLine
 */
@JsonProperty("landLine")
public void setLandLine(Integer landLine) {
    this.landLine = landLine;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder().append(mobile).append(landLine).append(additionalProperties).toHashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if ((other instanceof PhoneNo) == false) {
        return false;
    }
    PhoneNo rhs = ((PhoneNo) other);
    return new EqualsBuilder().append(mobile, rhs.mobile).append(landLine, rhs.landLine).append(additionalProperties, rhs.additionalProperties).isEquals();
}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. You post a JSON Schema and ask how to "fetch properties of pojo class". There's like a dozen of interpretations of what you mean. Be specific and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226110/loading-a-map-using-properties-class/32226264#32226264

Comment: I want create runtime pojo classes for my json schema.from pojo classes I want to fetch each fields and there types.from that fields I want to create query for mongodb. means in this case I have Employee pojo class in that I have Address class embedded having fields landMark,zipcode.so I want to read fields and make query as Employee.Address.landMark

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "fetch fields". In your comment you say "fetch fields and their types". That indicates that you want to use reflection to find out which fields your classes have. But you also sound like you want to get the value of some of the fields.

Are you trying to make some code where the input is an object of type Employee and the output is a mongodb query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Class)` . Here you have an example usage of that mechanism: [Java Beans Introspector](http://codereligion.com/beware-of-java-beans-introspector/)

Comment: Hi @Kris thanks for answer.I tried with your given solution in this case  its working same  as my previous logic.I am not able to fetch properties of contained pojo class.I just want to fetch fields and types from evry pojo class which contains in one pojo.Is there any other way? or we have to read manually.

Comment: You can read the type of the field I think, once you know that you dig deeper with beans Inspector I guess.

Comment: I tried with beans Inspector but I am not able to fetch embedded pojo class. can you give some examle? thanks