# How to test the "key" and "value" of config.properties file?

Tags: java, testing, junit4, properties-file

I have a class ReadPropertyFile which has a method getPropertyFor() of return type string(which is the value corresponding to key passed as parameter).I need help to test the getPropertyFor() method for both value and the key using Junit.

```
 public class ReadPropertyFile {


        private Properties properties;
        public ReadPropertyFile(String propertyFileName) {

            properties= new Properties();
            try {
                properties.load(new FileReader(propertyFileName));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public String getPropertyFor(String key) {

            String value = properties.getProperty(key);
            if(value == null) {
                try {
                    throw new Exception(key + " not found!");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
```

I have written the following test case to test the value for the key provided.

How do I test the "key" whether it is contained in the testconfig.properties file?
The contents of the testConfig.properties are as follows:
FILE_NAME=D:/Refreshed_data_daily/all_hue_posts_in_excel.xlsx

Comment: You have already written getPropertyFor(key) method. Did you face any issue?

Comment: Yeah I have written a test case for checking if the value is correct:
@Test
 public void testIfFilePathValueExists(){
  ReadPropertyFile checkKey= new ReadPropertyFile("testConfig.properties");
  assertEquals(checkKey.getPropertyFor(fileNameKey), "D:/Refreshed_data_daily/all_hue_posts_in_excel.xlsx");
 }

Comment: How do I write test case for checking the key value?

Comment: Your text file will have entries like key1=value1 key2=value2  etc. Check for the key name present in the file. I prefer Preferences to properties as per my post in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226110/loading-a-map-using-properties-class/32226264#32226264

Answer (score 0):

If the key is not defined in the file,
the `getProperties` method returns `null`.
If the key exists but has no value,
the `getProperties` method returns an empty string.
The way you catch and throw exception in the file doesn't make much sense.
You could simplify your method as:

```
public String getPropertyFor(String key) {
    return properties.getProperty(key);
}
```

Given this content in `testConfig.properties`:

```
FILE_NAME = D:/Refreshed_data_daily/all_hue_posts_in_excel.xlsx
empty.test =
```

You could unit test the different cases like this:

```
private String getProperty(String key) {
    new ReadPropertyFile("testConfig.properties").getPropertyFor(key)
}

@Test
public void testMissingKey() {
      assertNull(getProperty("nonexistent"));
}

@Test
public void testEmptyKey() {
      assertEquals("", getProperty("empty.prop"));
}

@Test
public void testValue() {
      assertEquals("D:/Refreshed_data_daily/all_hue_posts_in_excel.xlsx", getProperty("FILE_NAME"));
}
```

Comment: The test case which you have written tests if either of the key or value is missing. An NoSuchElementException will be thrown if any of these values will be missing. right?
How do I write test case to check the correctness of the key? similar to the test case I have written for the value

Comment: Just for testing purpose I cannot add "empty.pro" key with null value and test it. I want to check specifically for the key "FILE_NAME". How  would be the test case? Because that is the only key I'm using in my program, there are no other keys!

Comment: The `testValue` method in my answer does that. `FILE_NAME` must exist in the file, and it must have a specific value. If the key has a different name, or a different value, the test case will fail.

Comment: Can't there be a separate test case to check only key? something like AssertEquals(myObj.getTheKey(), "FILE_NAME")

Comment: No, such test doesn't make sense. In a `Properties` object there's no "the key". There are many keys. They have names, like "FILE_NAME" in your example. It's a list of key -> value pairs.

Comment: Is there anything else you need? Care to upvote / accept ?