# Java System.getProperties()

Tags: java, properties, hashtable

I have a problem in writing one method:

The method should load the properties from `System.getProperties()` and store them in variable `Hashtable`, which is a class variable.

```
Properties p = System.getProperties();
```

This is how I get them but I have no idea how to store the whole properties list in `Hashtable`

I also wonder if the class should look like this or no:

```
public class Collection extends Hashtable<Object, Object>
```

Comment: Properties is a legacy class. Have a look at preferences : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226110/loading-a-map-using-properties-class/32226264#32226264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`System.getProperties()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--) returns a [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) object that inherits from [`Hashtable<Object,Object>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html).

Therefore, you can simply use:

```
Hashtable<Object,Object> hashtable = System.getProperties();
```

Comment: and the class should like as i wrote it? ^

Comment: @MyStaa No your class does not need to extend `Hashtable`.

Comment: No problem !! :D And could you help with the second question? ;) or with this one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319180/java-properties-hashtable-print)