# Why am I getting java.lang.StackOverflowError in my code?

Tags: java

In my java class I have a `static` method called `getProperties()` that returns `java.util.Properties`.

In another `static` method I am calling that method like:

```
Properties p = getProperties();
```

And the `getProperties()` method:

```
    private static Properties getProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try{         
            InputStream fis = null;                
            fis = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/fileName.properties"); //In DEBUG mode control comes until here and returns to Properties p = getProperties(); in the calling method every time continuously 
            properties.load(fis);
            fis.close();            
        }catch(Exception e){
            //......
        }
        return properties;
    }
```

ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.misc.VM.isBooted(VM.java:165)
    at java.util.Hashtable.initHashSeedAsNeeded(Hashtable.java:226)
    at java.util.Hashtable.<init>(Hashtable.java:263)
    at java.util.Hashtable.<init>(Hashtable.java:283)
    at java.util.Properties.<init>(Properties.java:143)
    at java.util.Properties.<init>(Properties.java:135)
```

While in debug mode getProperties(); method gets called continuously without reaching return statement.

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: Not directly related: move the `fis.close();` to the (non-existant!) `finally` clause. If you get an exception you would have the `FileInputStream` open.

Comment: Can you share the contents of that file? Perhaps there's something funky going on there?

Comment: Are you using maven? Because that looks like a mavenized path.

Comment: I am using Java 7. Yes I am using maven. When I tried moving fis.close(); into finally block and run it, but no luck.

Comment: @Mureinik May I know contents of the file means what?

Comment: @TheGuest what's inside the file. Perhaps something there is causing the problem.

Comment: Can you publish the contents of file? Apart from the issue, move away from legacy class Properties. preferences is ideal choice. Have a look at this SE question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226110/loading-a-map-using-properties-class/32226264#32226264

Comment: Can you show us the properties file?

Comment: How big is your file?

Answer (score 0):

I excuted the code it's ok,but I think the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError`, Perhaps something there is causing the problem.

```
Properties p = new Properties();
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/fileName.properties"));
p.load(fs);
```

Comment: How is this different from what they have? What difference will this make? Why are you suggesting it?

Comment: How do the contents of a file cause a `StackOverflowError`?

Comment: What do I think about what? I'm asking you to clarify your answer because I don't see how it's relevant. Your code is pretty much the same as theirs. Your suggestion about `StackOverflowError`, at first glance, seems impossible. Please clarify your answer.

Answer (score -1):

StackOverflowError occurs because your code is calling a static method multiple number of times, can you post the entire code so that we can see why getProperties method is not reaching return ? Thanks

Comment: "While in debug mode getProperties(); method gets called continuously without reaching return statement".   So I believe that the static method that calls getProperties is error prone