# Java reflection type cast array

Tags: java, reflection, properties

I am storing information from the fields of an entity class `Config` in a `properties file` as key/value pairs.

```
fieldName1 = fieldValue1  
fieldName2 = fieldValue2  
...
```

Until now I hardcoded it

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("pathToExe", config.getPathToExe()); 
// ...
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(configFile), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
props.store(writer, "");
writer.close();
```

But as I want to continuously extend the properties I was thinking about making it dynamic.
`Config` has fields of types `String`,`String[]` and `int`.
I read about reflection in Java but I am not familiar with it, see my code below:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
Field[] fields = config.getClass().getFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    if (!field.getName().equals("oberservers")) {
        // is it a String[] field?
        if (field.getType().isArray()) {
            try {
                props.setProperty(field.getName(), String.join(";", /* how can I cast my String[] field here? */ );
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            try {
                props.setProperty(field.getName(), field.get(config).toString());
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
   }
}
// ...
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(configFile), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
props.store(writer, "");
writer.close();
```

How can I cast my `String[]` field?
Is this a clean approach at all or is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like what you're really trying to do is serialize/deserialize a `Config` object. Consider using other more flexible mechanisms instead of `Properties`...

Comment: What happens when you use `(String[])field.get(config)`? Anyway maybe you should take a look at something simpler like JSON.

Comment: in the string array case just cast: `(String[])field.get(config)`

Comment: Consider using Preferences (with xml) instead of legacy Properties. Have a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226110/loading-a-map-using-properties-class/32226264#32226264

Comment: and this link :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html

Comment: Regarding to your comments I will try my luck with the [Commons Configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/index.html) library.